# Handle javascript Null Object from PHP

Tags: javascript, laravel, null

I have a `string` in `javascript` which contains an `if statement` in order to handle `null values`.

```
var id = properties[index].id;`
```

This variable above might have not a value, when this happens the:

```
console.log(id);
```

returns *null*

and the

```
typeof id
```

returns an `object`

In my string i have an if condition in order to check if is null but the process fails

```
var content = "@if(null !==" + id + ")<a href='people?person_id="+ id +"' target='_blank'>"+ owner + "," +"</a>@endif";
```

I'm doing something wrong with the handling of `null`, in other occasions, for example `@if(id == 'somethingOtherThanTheId'){ the if condition is successfull }`

Comment: For what reason the down vote please?

Comment: Don't know who down-voted, but from where I stand: it's rather unclear what you're asking, nor do I understand why you tagged this question _PHP_. Either way, I don't know what throws you about `null` in JS, but its `typeof` is indeed _object_ for historic reasons be that as it may, your string containing the `if` _quotes_ `null`, whereas `null` is a value in its own right, so it needn't be quoted: `if (null !== id)` instead of `if ('null' !== id)` would be my guess

Comment: Thanks for your answer the quotes where my mistake, i put them in my question by mistake. In the running code there are not any quotes.

Answer (score 0):

1. null is not string, you should check it like `if (id !== null)`
2. why you check in blade, why not in js:

   ```
   var content = (id !== null) ? "<a href='people?person_id="+ id +"' target='_blank'>"+ owner + "," +"</a>" : "";
   ```